# Hibernate Native query returned duplicated result in result array with group by added in query

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-native-query

I am using Hibernate version 3. 
My table has 9 columns  and my query looks like

```
select col1, count(col2), sum(col3), sum(col4) from table a
 where a.col5= 'criteria1' and a.col6 = 'criteria2' 
 and a.col7 = 'criteria3' and a.col8 = 'criteria4' group by col9
```

col2 is the id and primary key of the table.
When I run same query in query browser it gives me correct result.
For example, if result returned in browser was  test,10,**300,500**
Result returned through natove query was different ,and it was test,10,**10,10**

In native query result , 2nd column in result got duplicated to third and fourth columns. 
Observed this behavior only if **group by** is added to query. If I remove group by and sum on columns it returned correct results. I have researched on Google there seems to be an existing issue but no answer was found for this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding aliases to  `count` and `sum`  resolved the issue.

Fixed query looked like below one. changes are shown in bold.

```
select col1, count(col2) as count1, sum(col3) as sum1, sum(col4) as sum2 from table a
where a.col5= 'criteria1' and a.col6 = 'criteria2' 
and a.col7 = 'criteria3' and a.col8 = 'criteria4' group by col9
```